# Why this code doesnt work when i use button?

Tags: jquery

It doesnt work when i use button.

JQuery:

```
function changeSize() {
    $(this).animate({fontSize: "+=3px"});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on("click", "p", changeSize);
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="test">Click me</button>
<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `onclick` event on all `p` element which inside in `#test` so Put `p`  inside button then It will start work

```
<button id="test"> <p>Hello</p> Click me</button>
```

or do simply by taking another `div` as a parent of `button` and `p` and put `onclick` on `p` like below

```js
function changeSize() {
    console.log("Clicked");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div").on("click", "p", changeSize);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
<button id="test">Click me</button>
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

You can simply add `onclick` on `p` if you do not want to care about parent.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").on("click", changeSize);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your selector to select tag < p > inside button['id=test'], then you put your tag < p > outside of the button! 
*Actually, this is not a good idea! < p > is a paragraph tag and button cannot be a good parent for paragraph!!!*

You can use this samples:

```
<p>Hello <button id='test'>Click me</button></p>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on("click", changeSize);
});
```

This selector will only select #test for once and after that whenever you click on that button your code will take care of that button.

Or:

```
<p id='test'>Hello <button>Click me</button></p>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on("click", 'bottun', changeSize);
});
```

This will detect all your clicks on p#test and runs your code if the target was a paragraph tag, which is not a good idea at all. these type of selectors will reduce your code performance. Usually, you can use this selector to select an element that was appended to the DOM with javascript after that page was fully loaded (DOM was created and rendered). In this case, you can simply use the first selector above and your code will work just fine.